# How do I find out if my Pi's warranty is voided?

Tags: overclocking

How do I find out if my Pi's warranty is voided? I overclocked my Pi, but I didn't use the `force_turbo` setting.

Answer (score 4):

From [this document](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1627216.pdf) ([The Foundation doesn't handle warranty returns](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=28978)):

> Newark element14 has no obligation to repair, replace, or provide
>   refunds in the following  instances:
>
> - If the alleged defect arises because Customer has altered or repaired    the Raspberry pi  without the prior written consent or
>     authorization    of Newark element14
> - If Customer did not follow any applicable instructions for proper    storage, usage, or  maintenance of the Raspberry pi
> - If Customer has failed to notify Newark element14 of any defect where    the defect should  have been reasonably apparent on
>     inspection
> - If Customer fails to notify Newark element14 of the defect within 12    months of Newark  element14's shipment of Raspberry pi to
>     Customer.

Since the Raspberry Pi Foundation has declared the "standard" overclocking options safe, overclocking [no longer voids your warranty](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/2008):

> Since launch, we’ve supported overclocking and overvolting your
>   Raspberry Pi by editing config.txt. Overvolting provided more
>   overclocking headroom, but voided your warranty because we were
>   concerned it would decrease the lifetime of the SoC; we set a sticky
>   bit inside BCM2835 to allow us to spot boards which have been
>   overvolted.
>
> We’ve been doing a lot of work to understand the impact of voltage and
>   temperature on lifetime, and are now able to offer a “turbo mode”,
>   which dynamically enables overclock and overvolt under the control of
>   a cpufreq driver, **without affecting your warranty**.

So no, [there is no warranty "bit" that is set anymore](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=176865#p176865).

Comment: At http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt#Overclocking_options it says that there's a warranty "bit". I want to find out if that bit is activated.

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover that.  Basically, no.  There is no "bit" that is activated.

Comment: I mean't "Sticky Bit"

Comment: Look at the last link, or [this link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=44293).  Dom clarifies this whole mess for you near the end of the discussion.

Comment: From what I understand of what Dom said, the sticky / warranty bit will only be set if the pi is overvolted AND one of the following 3 - force_turbo is on, current_limit_override is on, temperature exceeeds 85 degrees (I'm assuming celsius)

Comment: I'll quote Dom: "In reality we've heard of no correlation between warranty bit being set and boards failing. I've not heard of anyone being refused a warranty replacement for a valid reason because the warranty bit is set. So, I'd say the warranty bit has very little meaning."

Answer (score 1):

In Raspberry Pi 2 and newer, you can check the warranty bit by looking at the revision code. There are two ways to look at the revision code:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

and

```
vcgencmd otp_dump
```

The documentation here shows what the revision code is contained within bank 30 of the otp_dump.

The newer style revision code places the warranty bit in the seventh bit position. If it is a 0, your warranty is intact. If 1, it has been voided by overclocking.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/revision-codes/README.md

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you bought it.  [Element 14](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1627216.pdf) for example will replace it unless you alter the device in some way.  If you overclocked the device using the built in method you should be fine.

Comment: What do you alter the device in the some way? I overclock my Pi using /boot/config.

Comment: The second comment in the thread below states where the bit is stored.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=44293

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way.